# How to add additional data to QAbstractView?

Tags: python, pyqt5

These questions are based on the original [editabletreemodel.py](https://github.com/baoboa/pyqt5/blob/master/examples/itemviews/editabletreemodel/editabletreemodel.py) using Pyqt5.8 and python 3.6. I have to add data from another entry (database) which come as dictonary and looks like

> dataSet = {'level': 0, 'dbID': 549, 'parent_ID': 3, 'short_name': 'Line5',
> 'long_name': '', 'order': 4}

short_name should be displayed in column 0 and long_name should be displayed in column 1 and the data should be kept for writing back to the database in QtUserRole. I insert the data by a function call:

```
TreeFunction.insertRow(self,self.ui.treeViewStructure, dataSet)
```

The data will be separeted (this function is a little bit modifed) in

```
def insertRow(self,view,dataSet):
    display = dataSet.short_name
    dbindex = dataSet
    index = view.selectionModel().currentIndex()
    model = view.model()

    if not model.insertRow(index.row()+1, index.parent()):
        return

    TreeFunction.updateActions(self,view)

    for column in range(model.columnCount(index.parent())):
        child = model.index(index.row()+1, column, index.parent())
        model.setData(child, display, Qt.EditRole)
        model.setData(child, dbindex, Qt.UserRole)
```

I retrieve the data by the original **.data** function:

```
display = self.ui.treeViewStructure.selectionModel().currentIndex().data(Qt.DisplayRole)
dbindex = self.ui.treeViewStructure.selectionModel().currentIndex().data(Qt.UserRole)
print("item clicked DisplayRole:",display)
print("item clicked    UserRole:", dbindex)
```

with the result:

> item clicked DisplayRole: Line5
>
> item clicked    UserRole: None

The documentation in Qt Assistant says:

> Constant Qt::UserRole 0x0100 The first role that can be used for
> application-specific purposes.
>
> For user roles, it is up to the developer to decide which types to use
> and ensure that components use the correct types when accessing and
> setting data.

I understand this that I can any kind of data (int,string,dict, image, binary,...) store in QtUserRole, it works as container.
My questions:

1. Why is my UserRole from dbIndex not stored?
2. Do I have a wrong implementation in general or of the recordset from the database?
3. And, if yes: What is the correct way to handle recordsets or any other additional data?

Comment: Look at the definition of `TreeModel.setData()`. Do you see the problem?

Comment: Do you mean: `if role != Qt.EditRole:
return False`? Independent if I change or add a rule for **Qt.UserRole** there are no data stored. `result = item.setData(index.column(), value)` delivers true. but I can't get the UserRole data back from `item.data(Qt.UserRole)`

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. It's telling you that the model only supports one kind of data. If you hand trace the rest of the code in the method, that should become obvious. In particular, note that `TreeItem.setData()` does not take a `role` argument - so there's only one value per column (i.e. the displayed text).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. How can I add more? I'm sorry for silly questions but I'm new to pyqt.

Comment: It is a very bad idea to try to adapt some example code that was designed for a different purpose. I doubt that you need a custom model, which is an advanced approach, and difficult to get right. For a generic tree, you should either use a high-level convenience class like [QTreeWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html), or a [QStandardItemModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html) with a [QTreeView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html). I can't really say more than that, because I have no idea what kind of application you are trying to write.

Comment: Thanks, I changed to `QStandardItemModel` and now I have the possibility for `QtUserRole`. 
The application sounds simple: I generate a TreeView from 4 related tables of a sqlite database and want to write the changes back.